# how to keep 2013 nexus 7 in ptp mode when connected to pc

Tags: android, nexus-7

developing and android app using 6.0.1. while the tablets are connected in ptp mode initially, they seem to lose this overnight (pc is probably going to sleep).

is there some way to keep the these in ptp mode?

edit: stay awake when charging did not help. there is a ptp option under developer options, but it does not seems to stick either.

Comment: Probably it will not help if computer sleeps but there's option 'Stay awake when charging' under Developer Options in Settings menu.

Comment: does not seem to stick :(